# Getting list of devices plugged in in a pc (windows platform)

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-12-athens

I am working on a project and I need to get the list of plugged in devices in the PC, just like the Windows Device Manager does.

[image]

But I don't know how to communicate with Windows to retrive the list of available devices in Delphi Firemonkey framework. I am using Delphi 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that Device Manager does is done through the "SetupDi" APIs.  They are powerful, but very wordy.  The `devcon` tool from Microsoft also does all of these functions, and the source code is available:

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/setup/devcon

Please note that this is complicated.  Be patient, follow the sample.